# How do I make MPMusicPlayerController register changes in playlist?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmusicplayercontroller

I'm trying to build a music player app in xcode, but I'm having trouble when changing the playlist (a.k.a. the music player queue). Any time I change something in my playlist (i.e. when addind songs or changing song order, or when pressing the "next" button, etc.) I always seem to have to execute these tow lines of code:

```
[self.musicplayer play];
[self.musicplayer pause];
```

apparently, the music player only really registers changes when i send it the "play" command; soon after, i have to send it "pause", so that the song won't actually start playing.

without these lines of code, i would have the following problem (among others):
I would have, say, 6 songs, named "1" through "6". song 1 was playing, but i paused it. I then pressed the "next button" 3 times, which executed the following code (3 times):

```
[self.musicPlayer skipToNextItem];
```

therefore, by my logic, the music player should have song number 4 as its current playing song; but when I pressed play, song number 1 would start playing, as if it hadn't noticed I pressed "next".

I was only able to solve the problem by telling it to play and pause, as described above, but that was a very ugly solution, to say the least. also, in some cases, the ipod would play the first seconds of the song before processing it had to pause right away, and that was pretty bad :p

Does anyone know the correct way I should be doing this?

I am using Xcode 4.2.5 preview, and testing it on an iphone 4s with ios 6.

Comment: Can you put a bit more code into the question?